# Suggestion for Semantic Markup

Tags: html, css, markup, semantic-markup

I am creating a web GUI for an application I am working on. This particular section will sit within a larger page that is of a good semantic makeup. However, I am unsure what the best option to markup the below screen semantically.

My initial thought is to separate the top half from the bottom half via divs. Therefore, markup for the top is pretty easy. Leaving the bottom which is where I feel stumped. The easiest answer is a table but this content doesn't easily fit the only use tables for tabular data rule. Especially considering that headers would look conspicuous in this layout. Suggestions?

[Need Semantic Markup for this Image http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/2261/semanticmarkup.png](http://img183.imageshack.us/img183/2261/semanticmarkup.png)

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. ;)

Comment: I think the fact that you are asking this question means your HTML/CSS is already far better than most web sites, so don't sweat it :)

Comment: You should change the design of the "Delete" button, so that it is not the same as "Open" (risk of confusion)

Comment: @unor Definitely agree and we ultimately did. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a table for the lower portion because in my opinion this *is* tabular data.  I see 4 columns (icon, project name, project description, and action buttons).  I don't see any reason to not use a table for this layout (not to mention that any other approach that would make this layout scale properly would require JavaScript and a lot of headaches to work right).

Comment: Without column headings though I am violating a rule of semantic markup?

Comment: @ahsteele you can add the headings ... and hide through css - which would be a styling decision, your html doesn't need to suffer because of it

Comment: Technically yes, but good web development is a balancing act between idealism and pragmatism.

Comment: @OP: I would also use tables. I'm not sure what you mean by "...headers would look conspicuous..." -- so don't include headers. :-) Trying to do this without tables in any kind of broadly-browser-compatible way will be complex, difficult to maintain, and error-prone -- e.g., not a useful way to spend valuable development time. Someday CSS will be both up to it in a *reasonable* way and the necessary features for it will be well-enough supported, but while there may be an argument today for the former, there isn't for the latter. Don't waste your time.

Comment: @ahsteele: "Without column headings though I am violating a rule of semantic markup?" No, headerless tables are fine for this sort of thing. Moreover, "semantic markup" (outside academia) is just a guideline and is much more important for textual data than this sort of presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would be the most egregious violation of semantic markup if you put that stuff in tables.  Except for the buttons, it looks pretty tabular to me.  I think the CSS gods would absolve you :)

Comment: as Andrew said in his answer - the buttons belong to an actions column

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrew.  This is tabular data so you should use a `<table>` but keep in mind that you should define table headers, columns, and footers properly.

Your other option is to go with a headerless table where you would use a `<div>`for the header and footer and a `<table>` as the body.  However, I don't recommend doing this.  One reason would be you would want headers for things like client-side sorting if you're using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You're not violating anything putting that in a table form. Sure, some people will whine about it, but it's close enough to tabular data that you may as well.